# java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectComplete" failed (expected: onComplete(); actual: onError(org.springframework.r2dbc.BadSqlGrammarExceptio

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, h2

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.0 and looking to

1. Read application-test.properties to create H2 DB while running the test cases only
2. 

Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectComplete" failed (expected: onComplete(); actual: onError(org.springframework.r2dbc.BadSqlGrammarException: execute; bad SQL grammar [create table account (
    id INT auto_increment,
    user_name VARCHAR(50),
    balance INT
);

create table money_deposit_event (
    id INT auto_increment,
    account_number INT,
    amount INT,
    foreign key (account_number) references account(id),
    check (amount > 99) -- business rule says there should be min $100 deposit
);

insert into account (user_name, balance) values
     ('Tara', 0),
     ('Daisy', 0),
     ('Fredericka', 0),
     ('Brita', 0);]; nested exception is io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcBadGrammarException: [90057] [90057] Constraint "PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE (ID)" not found; SQL statement:
create table money_deposit_event (
    id INT auto_increment,
    account_number INT,
    amount INT,
    foreign key (account_number) references account(id),
    check (amount > 99) -- business rule says there should be min $100 deposit
) [90057-212]))
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.assertionError(MessageFormatter.java:115)
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.failPrefix(MessageFormatter.java:104)
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.fail(MessageFormatter.java:73)
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.failOptional(MessageFormatter.java:88)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.lambda$expectComplete$4(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:336)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$SignalEvent.test(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:2218)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onSignal(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1490)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onExpectation(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1438)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onError(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1091)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onError(MonoIgnoreElements.java:84)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoUsingWhen$MonoUsingWhenSubscriber.deferredError(MonoUsingWhen.java:277)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$RollbackInner.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:475)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:209)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:209)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$maybeRecycleAndDrain$19(SimpleDequePool.java:554)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.onComplete(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:135)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDoFinally.java:145)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4515)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4371)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4307)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.maybeRecycleAndDrain(SimpleDequePool.java:548)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueuePoolRecyclerInner.onComplete(SimpleDequePool.java:765)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueuePoolRecyclerMono.subscribe(SimpleDequePool.java:877)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:220)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1817)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:62)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onError(MonoIgnoreElements.java:84)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onError(FluxFilter.java:157)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxFilter.java:291)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:265)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onError(FluxUsingWhen.java:364)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoStreamCollector$StreamCollectorSubscriber.onError(MonoStreamCollector.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:842)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(FluxFlatMap.java:451)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:544)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:842)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.innerError(FluxFlatMap.java:863)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(FluxFlatMap.java:990)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:142)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:272)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:964)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:426)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray$ArraySubscription.slowPath(FluxArray.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray$ArraySubscription.request(FluxArray.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray.subscribe(FluxArray.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray.subscribe(FluxArray.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromFluxOperator.subscribe(MonoFromFluxOperator.java:81)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoUsingWhen$ResourceSubscriber.onNext(MonoUsingWhen.java:183)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetry$RetrySubscriber.onNext(FluxRetry.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
    at io.r2dbc.pool.MonoDiscardOnCancel$MonoDiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onNext(MonoDiscardOnCancel.java:92)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:236)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:220)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1817)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:62)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at io.r2dbc.pool.MonoDiscardOnCancel.subscribe(MonoDiscardOnCancel.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
    at reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.deliver(AbstractPool.java:469)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$drainLoop$9(SimpleDequePool.java:423)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(FluxDoOnEach.java:154)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.subscribe(MonoSupplier.java:62)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:258)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:78)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:8642)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8439)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8363)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.drainLoop(SimpleDequePool.java:453)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.pendingOffer(SimpleDequePool.java:600)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.doAcquire(SimpleDequePool.java:296)
    at reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.request(AbstractPool.java:432)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueueBorrowerMono.subscribe(SimpleDequePool.java:720)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetry$RetrySubscriber.resubscribe(FluxRetry.java:117)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetry.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetry.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4385)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoUsingWhen.subscribe(MonoUsingWhen.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.toVerifierAndSubscribe(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:867)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:823)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:815)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.verifyComplete(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:682)
    at com.example.r2dbctransaction.R2dbcTransactionApplicationTests.initDB(R2dbcTransactionApplicationTests.java:60)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:126)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:68)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:397)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:209)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
    Suppressed: org.springframework.r2dbc.BadSqlGrammarException: execute; bad SQL grammar [create table account (
    id INT auto_increment,
    user_name VARCHAR(50),
    balance INT
);
```

Test Case:

```
package com.example.r2dbctransaction;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.R2dbcEntityTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.util.StreamUtils;

import com.example.r2dbctransaction.entity.Account;
import com.example.r2dbctransaction.repository.AccountRepository;
import com.example.r2dbctransaction.request.DepositRequest;
import com.example.r2dbctransaction.service.BankService;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;


@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class R2dbcTransactionApplicationTests {

    @Value("classpath:init.sql")
    private Resource initSql;

    @Autowired
    private R2dbcEntityTemplate entityTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private BankService bankService;

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository repository;

    @BeforeAll
    public void initDB() throws IOException {
        String query = StreamUtils.copyToString(initSql.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Mono<Void> mono = this.entityTemplate
                .getDatabaseClient()
                .sql(query)
                .then();

        StepVerifier.create(mono)
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void transactionSuccess() {
        DepositRequest request = DepositRequest.create(1, 500);
        Mono<Account> mono = this.bankService.deposit(request)
                .then(getAccountDetails(request));
        StepVerifier.create(mono)
                .expectNextMatches(ac -> ac.getBalance() == 500)
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    void transactionFailure() {
        DepositRequest request = DepositRequest.create(1, 99);
        Mono<Account> mono = this.bankService.deposit(request)
                .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.empty())
                .then(getAccountDetails(request));
        StepVerifier.create(mono)
                .expectNextMatches(ac -> ac.getBalance() == 500)
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    private Mono<Account> getAccountDetails(DepositRequest request){
        return this.repository.findById(request.getAccount())
                    .doOnNext(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Referential constrains can reference only primary key or unique columns, but you don't have a primary key or unique constraint on `account(id)`.

Also it is a bad idea to use `auto_increment` clause from MySQL in H2 unless MySQL or MariaDB compatibility modes are enabled, H2 can reject this clause depending on settings.

`id INT auto_increment` needs to be replaced with `id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY` in definitions of all tables.

If table definitions are generated by JPA, you need to check presence of `@Id` annotation on `id` fields in entities.